# Adding comments to a WSDL output from WCF/.Net

Tags: wcf, wsdl

based on the WSDL spec from W3 there is the possibility to add "wsdl:document" tags to the WSDL output so that people using that webservice have a better explanation/documentation about this webservice.

Does anybody know how to make WCF use these comments/descriptions, or how to write the code in C# that those comments are exported as part of the wsdl?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 12):

It seems that the community project [WCFExtras](https://github.com/lamronby/wcfextrasplus) on GitHub provides a work-around the limitations of .NET 3.5.

Comment: Just tried it - works like a charm even if my solution is in .NET 4.0. Thanx Joannes

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing your design / coding in C# classes, adorned with [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract], then I don't know of any way to export documentation you might have on those classes and methods into the WSDL, unfortunately.

I was appalled by that too - I expected any /// comments on my classes and methods to show up in the WSDL - no luck :-(

Our solution now is this:
1) we create a basic "mockup" of our service interface with all operations in C#
2) we compile that into an assembly
3) we extract the metadata (WSDL, XSD) from that assembly and then throw away the C# "prototype"
4) we manually add comments (xs:annotation/xs:documentation) to the WSDL and XSD
5) from now on, the WSDL/XSD are the master - and we generate our interface from those descriptions

Cumbersome and annoying, but it works fairly ok for us.

I sure hope VS2010 / WCF 4.0 will bring us a bit more support in this area !!

Marc

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040.aspx

I think this will do what you want but it only will work for .NET clients.

Answer (score 1):

WCF won't do it on it's own unfortunately. There are extensibility points for WSDL generation that you can use to accomplish this at least partially: Look up the  [IWSDLExportExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx) interface.

Comment: Thanks - but that's just a first step. What I'd really like is the ability to export any "/// comments...." I made on the ServiceContract, OperationContract and DataContract into the WSDL and XSD. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebService(Namespace = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", **Description**="V0.2.42")]
```

Description put whatever you want in the .NET 4.0, not sure which versions... Probably a little late in answering, but answers seem more complex than required to add a blurb to WSDL only devs see.