# How to add comment in WCF proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any attribute that I can add to Operation contract which will have the comment as attribute value and it will be used to generates comments in the proxy?

Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: maybe you could elaborate a little on what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answers your question:
[adding-comments-to-a-wsdl-output-from-wcf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655234/adding-comments-to-a-wsdl-output-from-wcf-net)